# How to view images on public storage

Tags: laravel

I know this question has been asked too often, but my case is a little different.
I have a form by which I can upload pictures. It was working just fine and I could get preview of or download images after uploading. I don't know why, but today I couldn't get files downloading or even previewing (I just updated some authorization rules related to some controllers which have nothing to do with this); they are uploaded well, but when I try to access them via `127.0.0.1:8000/storage/image.png` an abort page says `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found`. I still can view the images I uploaded yesterday, but not those I uploaded today. Even If I copy an image manually, it won't open up in the browser.

I have also generated the link using `storage:link`.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by deleting `/public/storage` and do a simple `php artisan storage:link` again.